# How do i go through two lists with a for each or other method in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a question, in vb.net, how do I go through two lists with a for each or another method?

for example i have defined 3 list

```
Public NSPS As New List(Of String)
Public CONTENEDOR As New List(Of String)
Public IDCONTENEDOR As New List(Of String)
```

I have 2 excel files with the same variable CONTENEDOR, and in the other its called IDCONTENEDOR

So i need to create a third excel file that finds the rows with the same IDcontenedor and it adds the variable NSPS as appropriate, to that row in the new excel .
What is the correct way to go through 2 lists with 2 cycles in vb.net

to just fill information in a new excel i use this code

```
Dim aux As Integer = 1
While (aux <= CONTENEDOR.Count)
    hoja1.Cells("B" & aux + 1).Value = NPLANILLA.Item(aux - 1)
    aux += 1
End While
aux = 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand the question, but if what you want to do is step through multiple containers in a single loop, for this case, I'd suggest to just do it by index since they're all lists.  In other circumstances, you might work with the enumerators directly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem. The following answer is based on the best guess I could make.

To find a value corresponding to a key or id, use a dictionary. Dictionaries are much faster than loops for lookups.

```
Dim dict As new Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

Assuming that the 2 variables CONTENEDOR and IDCONTENEDOR have the same length and that the first list contains the values corresponding to the ids at the same index, you can fill the dictionary with

```
For i As Integer = 0 To CONTENEDOR.Count - 1
    dict.Add(IDCONTENEDOR(i), CONTENEDOR(i))
Next
```

Now given an id of type `String`, you can get the value with

```
Dim value As String
If dict.TryGetValue(id, value) Then
    NSPS.Add(value)
Else
    ' We did not find a value with this id.
End If
```

I am not sure where you get the id from, maybe from `NPLANILLA.Item(aux - 1)`? If it is typed as `Object` then convert it to `String`:

```
Dim id As String
id = CType(NPLANILLA.Item(aux - 1), String)
```